# Why axios can't send FormData on mobile google chrome on Android?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I made frontend for my site use ReactJS(`npm create-react-app`).
I ran into a problem uploading files, via Axios:

```
 const handleSubmit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData()

    files.forEach(file => {
      formData.append('files', file.file)
    })

    axios.postForm('http://example.com/upload-photo', formData, {
      headers: {Authorization: 'QWERTY'},
    }).then(res => {
      console.logres()
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

This code works fine in google chrome on desktop. But I get this error in google chrome on my android phone:

```
{
  "message": "Network Error",
  "name": "AxiosError",
  "stack": "AxiosError: Network Error\n at b.onerror (http://example.com/static/js/main.24638a12.js:2:1202448)",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "adapter": [
      "xhr",
      "http"
    ],
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Authorization": "Bearer QWERTY"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "http://example.com/upload-photo",
    "data": {}
  },
  "code": "ERR_NETWORK",
  "status": null
}
```

```
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```

What could be the problem? Or is the problem not with Axios?

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: @PooriaSet No, I'm using my personal android phone

Comment: If protocol is `HTTPS`, are you sure domain certificate is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider a few things:

1. If you are working on an **emulator**, make sure to use the IP address
   `10.0.2.2`.
2. If the protocol is `HTTPS`, ensure that the `SSL certificate` is valid.
3. Setting the `Content-Type`: `multipart/form-data` explicitly fixes the error. If you don't set it explicitly, then the default value is set here to application/x-www-form-urlencoded -> https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.27.2/lib/defaults/index.js#L10 and that apparently makes the request fail on `Android`.

I would recommend studying [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/973#issuecomment-437221047) issue and [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4823) on github.

Comment: Oh my god) Setting the header: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` really helped me.

It's very strange, but axios in google chrome on desktop was calculating this header itself for example: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYbLPh2iOfA8cgHAz` and worked fine.

But google chrome on my phone(android) did not work. Until I specified this header..... 

Thanks a lot for your help!)